# NHibernate - Business layer testing with in-memory SQLite database. How to change database configuration?

Tags: sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, integration-testing, in-memory-database

I use Fluent NHibernate code to create a MySQL database SessionFactory. No config files (just one value for the connection string in configuration - connectionStrings section of configuration file).

The SessionFactory creation code is contained in a Data tier class: SessionFactoryManager, which implements a singleton internal SessionFactory which is used by the Data and Business tiers to get all the sessions via SessionFactoryManager.OpenSession().

Some of my Business tier methods internally call SessionFactoryManager.OpenSession() to create sessions in a way that is transparent to the Presentation layer. So, when calling this methods there is no parameter or return value involving a session (to keep the Presentation layer "session-agnostic" when using those Business tier methods).

My problem comes when I write the integration tests for the Business layer: I would like to make them run on a SQLite in-memory database. I create a SessionFactoryManager which uses Fluent configuration to configure the SQLite database.

But when testing those methods that internally create the session, I can not tell them to use my testing SessionFactory (configured to use SQLite). So the "real" SessionFactory is called, and so the MySql database is used, not the SQLite.

I'm thinking of several possible solutions, but none of them seems right.

I could migrate the NHibernate configuration in Data layer to config files, and make different NHibernate config files for development/production and test environments, but I really would prefer to keep on with Fluent code.

I could also modify my Data layer to use a single configuration value, databaseMode or similar, that sets the database to be used: testing in-memory or the real one. And write some switch(databaseMode) statements like "case inMemory: { ... fluent code for in-memory SQLite... } case standard: { ... fluent code for standard database ... }". I don't like this approach at all, I don't want to modify my Data tier code functionality just for testing purposes.

Notice that I'm not testing Data layer, but Business layer. Not interested in testing NHibernate mappings, Dao or similar functionality. I already have unit tests for that, running OK with SQLite database.

Also, changing database is not a requirement of my application, so I'm not quite interested in implementing significant changes that allow me to dynamically change the DBMS, I only came to this need in order to write the tests.

A significant point: when using in-memory SQLite the database connection must be the same for all new sessions, otherwise the database objects are not available to the new sessions. So when creating a new session with SessionFactory.OpenSession() a parameter "connection" must be provided. But this parameter should not be used with non in-memory database. So the switch(databaseMode) should be used for any single session creation! Another Data layer code change that I don't like at all.

I'm seriously considering giving up and running my tests with the real database, or at least on an empty one, with its objects created and dropped for any test execution. But with this the test execution will surely be slower. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my solution was Inversion Of Control: I changed my data tier so I can inject a custom SessionFactoryBuilder class that makes the Fluently.Configure(...) magic.

In my data tier I use the "real" MySqlSessionFactoryBuilder, in my test projects I write TestMySqlFactoryBuilder or TestSQLiteSessionFactoryBuilder classes, or whatever I need.

I still have problems with SQLite feature that requires that the same connection is used for all sessions, and must be passed as a parameter in every ISession.Open() call. By the moment I have not modified my data tier to add that feature, but I would like to do it in the future. Probably by adding to my SessionFactory singleton a static private member to store the connection used to make SchemaExport, and a static private boolean member like PreserveConnection to state that this connection must be stored in that private member and used in every ISession.Open(). And also wrap ISession.Open() and make sure that no session is opened directly.